# Как на форумах проверяется просмотрено ли сообщение?

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте.

К примеру возьмем почти любой современный форум. Когда появляется какое то сообщение в какой либо теме - она отмечается каким то отличительным цветом или тому подобное (т.е. как бэ намекает что она обновилась) . Причём для каждого пользователя это сделано индивидуально. Вопрос : как это реализовано? Продумывал некоторые варианты. Но везде фигурирует огромная таблица с over90000 записей. Есть ли более "изящные" способы? :)

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

90к это не огромная. у каждого сообщения есть как правило ограниченное число получателей. соответвенно создаем связанную таблицу с тремя полями id (index) msg_id и user_id, в которую и добавляем записи о новом сообщении, после просмотра удаляем запись по индексу.

Comment: т.е. это вполне нормально?

Comment: с использованием индекса это будет достаточно шустренько и вполне нормально. к примеру у меня на 2,5кк записей строка по индексу удаляется за 0.0003 сек

Comment: ясно , спасибо :)